# Qt QML draw in cpp subclass

Tags: c++, qt, qml

so I am trying to understand drawing in Qt, but I dont get this one:
So first of all I had a qml file where I embedded a custom class called Game which has this constructor: `Game::Game(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem(parent)`
Writing `setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);` in the constructor code was sufficient to being able to draw with `QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *);` using `QSGGeometry` (This worked). Now I tried to draw in a subclass, using the same procedure but now it does not work anymore: So what I did was create a class called `qcurver`, and in Game I create an instance of `qcurver`. `QCurver` has the same constructor like Game and I pass the parent of Game so that technically it has the same parent as Game, but now when I try to draw in this class, nothing happens. Does anyone know, how I can pass the QML object for drawing, so that I actually see the drawing?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Magnus2552! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article how to create good question. I think you will not get right answer until posting appropriate code describing you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `Game` object from QML code, so it's registered correctly in the QML scene. But the `QCurver` isn't created there, so it won't work.

Yes, it has the same parent, but it only means that if the parent gets deleted - the `QCurver` will be deleted too. Qt doesn't revise all QObjects that are added as children to find out if they are of type `QQuickItem` and should be rendered.

Also, QML itself was added to be able to avoid doing widget hierarchies in C++. So, compose hierarchies in QML. Or, if you want some of them in C++ for the performance reasons - then it is possible to do `QSGNode` hierarchies inside a `QQuickItem` (that's useful for rendering complex scenes with OpenGL).

Comment: So just to make sure I understood correctly: I have to inherit from QSGNode and use that inherited class inside a QQuickItem to make it work?

Comment: No, to work with nodes, it's necessary to know how would you do that with plain OprnGL. `QSGNode/QSGGeometry` is a thin wrapper around OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I finally got it working now. The trick was to create a custom class which inherits from QSGNode, in which you save all of your different QSGNode (The problem was that you can only have one parent QSGNode for one QQuickItem). So in this custom class you have one parent QSGNode as usual, but all the other QSGNodes are added via appendChildNode to this parent Node. This code example in particular helped me a lot: http://qt.apidoc.info/5.2.0/qtquick/qtquick-scenegraph-graph-graph-cpp.html